# Eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have added `mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar` in project build path but it's not working. I am not able to create connection in Database development perspective from eclipse Luna. I am using MySQL 5.5.44.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:793)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: which to use ? its recommended on mysql site that for MySQL Server version 4.1, 5.0, 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, connector version is 5.1

Comment: Is the MySQL driver added in Eclipse? Go to "Window > Preferences > Data Management > Connectivity > Driver Definitions". Filter with MySQL and post the output.

Comment: Yes, I have created driver definition with 5.1 version